# How to create AWS IAM service account with access and secret keys using terraform

Tags: terraform-provider-aws

I want to create IAM user (service account) with access and secret keys using terraform and not console. How can i do that? Thanks, Deepak

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [documentation for aws_iam_access_key](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_access_key) has a [full example](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_access_key#example-usage) of an IAM user with an access key. Please note that this will write the secret to the state file, so keep your state file secure.